# Showing that $\ell_p$ norms are equivalent for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

I'm trying to show that the the norms $||x||_p$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are all equivalent for $1 \leq p \leq \infty$, specifically for any $1 \leq  p <q$ there exists some $C >1 $such that
$$
1/C < ||x||_p/||x||_q <C
$$
I've tried to argue using young's inequality, where if $p'$ and $q'$ are the conjugate exponents of $p,q$ respectively we have
$$
||x||_p \leq \frac{1}{p'}\left(||x||_p\right)^{p'} \text{ and} ||x||_q \leq \frac{1}{q'}\left(||x||_q\right)^{q'} 
$$
This would give
$$
\frac{||x||_q}{||x||_p} \leq \frac{p'}{q'} \frac{\left(||x||_q\right)^{q'}}{\left(||x||_p\right)^{p'}} \leq \frac{p'}{q'} \frac{\left(||x||_q\right)^{q'}}{\left(||x||_p\right)^{p'}}
$$
But it doesn't really seem to lead anywhere useful. I'm sure I could find an answer on this site, but I'm rally only looking for hints. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any two norms are equivalent on a finite dimensional space. To show this is enough to show that any norm is equivalent to  $l_1$ norm. One way it is easy, take any normalized basis and use triangle inequality. To show the other way around assume the opposite, you would have a sequence which has norm 1 in one norm and goes to zero in another. So for any functional $x*$ it goes to zero and it means coefficients go to zero so the linear combination goes to zero as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be shown that all norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent. So the interest is finding the sharpest constants in the inequalities.

Fix $p, q \geq 1$. We want to make an estimate of the form $\lVert x \rVert_{p} \leq C\lVert x \rVert_q$. Use Holder's inequality with some $r \geq 1$ to be chosen later:
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n}|x_i|^p \leq (\sum_{i}|x_i|^{pr})^{1/r}n^{(r - 1)/r}.$$
Now it is convenient to assume $p \leq q$, and we get the desired estimate with a well chosen $r$. It remains to handle the case $p > q$.